# Are "magister" and "majesty" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

My teachers are 'Magisters.'

My king is his 'Majesty.'

My dragon is 'Majestic.'

Is there some etymological link between the Latin word for 'teacher' and the words we use for exaltation?

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative perspective (which I hope will be corrected/supplemented by those who have more linguistic knowledge), I don't think you need to go quite so far back to see the relation of these words. Though the actual developmental relationship traces back to PIE, as Ethan shows, there's a simple connection that exists *in Latin* and which any reflective Roman would have grasped, namely:

- *Maiestas* comes from *maior/maius*, which is the **comparative adjective form of *magnus***.
- *Magister* comes from *magis*, which is the **comparative adverb form of *magnus***.

Of course, *magis* and *maior* are not regularly formed, and hence we need to look further back to trace their common ancestry. But they both have a clear relationship to one of the most common adjectives in Latin: *magnus*.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. Looking up both words in a real dictionary would have shown this to be the case, and even Etymonline makes the connection clear: [majesty](https://www.etymonline.com/word/majesty#etymonline_v_2229) and [master](https://www.etymonline.com/word/master).

Answer (score 7):

If you limit your etymological range to Latin alone, no.

These three English words which you've listed *coincidentally* happen to have similar pronunciation in their first few syllables. Both *magister* and *majesty* find their roots in different Latin words:

> [majesty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/majesty#English) < *mājestās*
>   [majestic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/majestic#English) < *majesty-* + *-ic*
>   [magister](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magister#English) < *magister*

The Latin words themselves, however, from which these English words originate, do share the same roots; both ultimately arrive from the same Proto-Indo-European adjective, **méǵh₂s*:

> [mājestās](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maiestas#Latin) < *major* + *-tās* < **magjōs* < **méǵh₂yōs‎* < **méǵh₂s* + **-yōs*
>   [magister](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magister#Latin) < *magis* + *-tero* < *magnus* < **magnos* < **méǵh₂s*